# Remove Characters from string with replace not working

Tags: python, string, character-encoding

I have a number of strings from which I am aiming to remove charactars using replace. However, this dosent seem to wake. To give a simplified example, this code:

```
row = "b'James Bray,/citations?user=8IqSrdIAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII,1985,6020,188.12,42,1.31,76,2.38'"
row = row.replace("b'", "").replace("'", "").replace('b"', '').replace('"', '')
print(row.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

still ouputs this `b'James Bray,/citations?user=8IqSrdIAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII,1985,6020,188.12,42,1.31,76,2.38'` wheras I would like it to output `James Bray,/citations?user=8IqSrdIAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII,1985,6020,188.12,42,1.31,76,2.38`. How can I do this?

Edit: Updataed the code with a better example.

Comment: Did you mean that you would like `b'xyz'` as the output? You may be confusing strings with bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mistaking single quotes for double quotes. Simple *replace* `'b`:

```
>>> row = "xyz'b"
>>> row.replace("'b", "")
'xyz'
```

As an alternative to `str.replace`, you can simple *slice* the string to remove the unwanted leading and trailing characters:

```
>>> row[2:-1]
'James Bray,/citations?user=8IqSrdIAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII,1985,6020,188.12,42,1.31,76,2.38'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first `.replace`, change `b'` to `'b`. Hence your code should be:

```
>>> row = "xyz'b"
>>> row = row.replace("'b", "").replace("'", "").replace('b"', '').replace('"', '')
#                      ^ changed here
>>> print(row.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
xyz
```

I am assuming rest of the conditions you have are the part of other task/matches that you didn't mentioned here.

If all you want is to take the string before first `'`, then you may just do:

```
row.split("'")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed this to remove `'b`:

```
.replace("'b", '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
row = "b'James Bray,/citations?user=8IqSrdIAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII,1985,6020,188.12,42,1.31,76,2.38'"

b_string = ast.literal_eval(row)
print(b_string)
u_string = b_string.decode('utf-8')
print(u_string)
```

out:

```
b_string:b'James Bray,/citations?user=8IqSrdIAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII,1985,6020,188.12,42,1.31,76,2.38'
u_string: James Bray,/citations?user=8IqSrdIAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII,1985,6020,188.12,42,1.31,76,2.38
```

**The real question is how to convert a string to python object.**

You get a string which contains an a binary string, to convert it to python's binary string object, you should use `eval()`. `ast.literal_eval()` is more safe way to do it.

Now you get a binary string, you can convert it to unicode string which do not start with "b" by using `decode()`